# Issue Sonar FileWriter en Java

Tags: java, servicio, sonar

una consulta en sonar me muestra *Remove this use of "java.io.FileWriter"* pero yo necesito la libreria, en la ayuda sonar solo comenta que la libreria no realiza el mismo trabajo en todos los equipos o ambientes que se utilice, y pide removerla pero no se como estandarizar para que siempre sea igual independientemente de donde se utilice, dejo mi codigo a continuación:

```
public File llenarTxt(List<LogsPACsBean> result, File archivoTemporal) throws CfdiServiceException {
    LOGGER.debug("Entrando a llenarTxt() {}");
    String aEscribir = "";
    for(int ij=0;ij<result.size();ij++) {
        aEscribir = aEscribir.concat(" ERROR: " + result.get(ij).getMessageError() + "\n");
    }
    //Aqui muestra el error en la variable escribir
    try(FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivoTemporal)) {
        escribir.write(aEscribir);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(ERROR, e);
        throw new CfdiServiceException(ErrorEnum.EXC_OPER_NO_EXITOSA);
    }
    LOGGER.debug("Saliendo de llenarTxt() {}");
    return archivoTemporal;
}
```

Ya funciona y realiza bien la acción, solo es ese issue que me solicita sonar.
(https://monteverdi.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/sonar/project/issues?id=de.uni_freiburg.informatik.ultimate%3Amavenparent&issues=AVc1Z_oxNZkwq-7ldb8J&open=AVc1Z_oxNZkwq-7ldb8J)
Dejo documentación de sonar.

Comment: El problema no es con el uso o no de la clase que importas es que tienes declarado este atributo `FileWriter writer;` que no lo inicializas y luego lo usas en el código.

Comment: Hola, sigue el problema, de hecho sonar detecta el fileWriter y no permite utilizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que detecta sonarqube es que la implementación de esa clase no toma en cuenta caracteres especiales, por lo que si tus caracteres no son ASCII podría no solamente leerse mal, sino [causar problemas cuando quieras que las máquinas virtuales se comuniquen entre sí](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/x/FoL5AQ), o incluso [darte un conteo de caracteres erróneo en cadenas](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/x/JgAWCQ).

Este es un ejemplo de otra manera de hacer lo mismo que quieres, usar un writer para escribir en un archivo.

```
BufferedWriter escribir = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(archivoTemporal),"UTF-8"));
```